# Why is my Perlin noise not lining up properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, perlin-noise, unity3d-terrain

I have two scripts, one attached to a prefab with a mesh filterer and mesh renderer that creates Perlin noise meshes (`GenTerrain.cs`), another attached to an empty game object that handles terrain chunk spawning (`TerrainManager.cs`). Perlin noise generated for spawned game objects does not line up. It creates new Perlin noise terrain object when player position is far enough from the old tile.

GenTerrain.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int width = 10;
    public int height = 10;
    public float scale = 20.0f;
    public float xOffset = 0f;
    public float zOffset = 0f;

    [Header("Perlin Noise Settings")]
    public int numOctaves = 4;
    public float amplitude = 2f;
    public float persistence = 0.5f;

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private int[] triangles;

    public void GenerateTerrain()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        vertices = new Vector3[(width + 1) * (height + 1)];

        int i = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z <= height; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++)
            {
                float xCoord = (float)x / width * scale;
                float zCoord = (float)z / height * scale;
                float y = CalculatePerlinNoise(xCoord + xOffset, zCoord + zOffset);
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                i++;
            }
        }

        triangles = new int[width * height * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + width + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + width + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + width + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }

        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }

    private float CalculatePerlinNoise(float x, float z)
    {
        float y = 0f;
        for (int o = 0; o < numOctaves; o++)
        {
            float frequency = Mathf.Pow(2, o);
            float amplitudeFactor = Mathf.Pow(persistence, o);
            y += Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * frequency, z * frequency) * amplitude * amplitudeFactor;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

TerrainManager.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TerrainManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject chunk;
    public Transform player;
    private Dictionary<Vector3,GameObject> chunks = new Dictionary<Vector3, GameObject>();

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 roundedPlayerPos = RoundToNearestTen(player.position);
        if (!chunks.ContainsKey(roundedPlayerPos)) {
            Debug.Log("chunks");
            GameObject currChunk = Instantiate(chunk, roundedPlayerPos, Quaternion.identity);
            GenTerrain scripting = currChunk.GetComponent<GenTerrain>();

            scripting.xOffset = roundedPlayerPos.x;
            scripting.zOffset = roundedPlayerPos.z;
            scripting.GenerateTerrain();
            chunks.Add(roundedPlayerPos, currChunk);
        }
    }

    Vector3 RoundToNearestTen(Vector3 a) {
        return new Vector3(
            Mathf.RoundToInt(a.x/10)*10,
            Mathf.RoundToInt(a.y/10)*10,
            Mathf.RoundToInt(a.z/10)*10
            );
    }
}
```

Terrain prefab has width of 10, height of 10, scale of 4, 1 octave, amplitude of 4, and 0 persistence:

[image]

Comment: would suggest that each chunk is not picking up where the last left off